# updating macro used in multiple spreadsheets by multiple people

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a system using a set of Excel spreadsheets which are stored on a company shared drive and used by others around the company.  There is a version of the spreadsheet created from a template for each of our clients.  When I need to update a macro, I have to update the 100 iterations of the spreadsheet.  Is there a way to have a master that the spreadsheets use which will get picked up by everyone using the spreadsheets?

Right now I am exporting the macro to my hard drive and then importing it to each of the workbooks.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: Keep macros in one workbook, data in another workbook (or 100 copies of that workbook).  Or just have a stub macro in each data workbook that opens the main macro workbook from a central location.

Comment: How does that affect the performance of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Having macros in another workbook to the data doesn't impact the execution time of the macros - everything is in memory anyway.  Other performance times (e.g. how much time users spend opening / closing workbooks) will depend a lot on how your workflow is set up. (E.g. if the users only open one existing file once per day, then the load time won't be much different.  But if they open lots of files each day, and the data is small, but macros are large, there could be significant improvements due to only loading macros once.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a set of macros for every iteration of the worksheet, Have one workbook with the macros as the "key". Other workbooks can then call on the key workbook to do the macro work.

Changes you will have to do in the key workbook is within the macros. The values will have to be flexible to be initialized to the workbook calling on them. Once the key macros are set to the calling workbook, the macros can change that workbook.

Performance is enhanced because all new workbooks will have the same macros that wont need to be edited. They just need macros to call on the key workbook and its functions.

Future edits will only need to be made in the key workbook macros. 
This will work well if all copies of the workbook are in the same format, sheet #, names, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Store your macros in a master workbook in a single document on the network. Save that workbook as an add-in (filetype .xlam), and set the workbook properties IsAddin=True.

For each of the client workbooks, you can then add this add-in as a reference. All functions referred to by name will be referred to those functions in the add-in. This will allow you to just update the add-in at leisure, and all the other workbooks will re-load the updated add-in next time they are opened.